# Pass interface from fragment to activity in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, interface, fragment

I want to pass my interface object from my fragment to my new activity in Kotlin. I tried by sending as constructor parameters not working. I have tried sending local broadcast...not working. Below is the code.

*Myactivity.kt*

```
class Myactivity: Activity{
    // get interface ref object here
    interface Myinterface: Parcelable {
        fun someMethod(true:Boolean?)
    }
}
```

*Myfragment.kt*

```
class Myfragment: Fragment(), Myinterface{
    val interface: Myinterface
    val intent = Intent(activity,Myactivity::class.java)
    intent.putextra // or   putParcelableExtra??? // pass interface obj

    override fun someMethod(true:Boolean?) {

    }
}
```

Now I have implemented it in my fragment and the same ref I want to pass to my activity back through intent. How can I achieve this in Kotlin?

Any help is much appreciated. TIA

Comment: Without mentioning implementation, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is not clear to me yet. From a user perspective, what do you want to happen?

Comment: Have you implemented the necessary methods for `Parcelable`?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible and easier solutions is to extend your interface from `Serializable`

```
interface MyInterface : Serializable {
    fun someMethod()
}
```

and pass it with intent.

```
val intent = Intent(activity, Myactivity::class.java).apply {
    putExtra("interface", this@Myfragment)
}
```

Comment: I tried in this way, but every time in activity after assigning it from intent extra the interface obj is null.